# How to convert a wavetable for use with `OscillatorNode.setPeriodicWave`?

Tags: javascript, signal-processing, fft, web-audio-api

I would like use a custom waveform with a WebAudio `OscillatorNode`. I'm new to audio synthesis and still struggle quite a lot with the mathematics (I can, at least, program).

The waveforms are defined as functions, so I have the function itself, and can sample the wave. However, the `OscillatorNode.createPeriodicWave` method requires two arrays (`real` and `imag`) that define the waveform in the frequency domain.

The `AnalyserNode` has FFT methods for computing an array (of bytes or floats) in the frequency domain, but it works with a signal from another node.

I cannot think of a way to feed a wavetable into the `AnalyserNode` correctly, but if I could, it only returns a single array, while `OscillatorNode.createPeriodicWave` requires two.

**TLDR** Starting with a periodic function, how do you compute the corresponding arguments for `OscillatorNode.createPeriodicWave`?

Answer (score 2):

Since you have a periodic waveform defined by a function, you can compute the [Fourier Series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fourier_series) for this function.  If the series has an infinite number of terms, you'll need to truncate it.

This is a bit of work, but this is exactly how the pre-defined Oscillator types are computed.  For example, see the definition of the [square wave](https://webaudio.github.io/web-audio-api/#basic-waveform-phase) for the OscillatorNode.  The `PeriodicWave` [coefficients for the square wave](https://webaudio.github.io/web-audio-api/#oscillator-coefficients) were computed in exactly this way.

If you know the bandwidth of your waveform, you can simplify the work a lot by not having to do the messy integrals.  Just uniformly sample the waveform fast enough, and then use an [FFT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fast_Fourier_transform) to get the coefficients you need for the `PeriodicWave`.  Additional details on in the [sampling theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nyquist%E2%80%93Shannon_sampling_theorem).

Or you can just assume that sample rate of the `AudioContext` (typically 44.1 kHz or 48 kHz) is high enough and just sample your waveform every 1/44100 or 1/48000 sec and compute the FFT of the resulting samples.

Comment: Thanks. Computing the FFT is the issue I'm having. I don't know how to implement that. The API implements an FFT for its `PeriodicWave` methods, but doesn't expose it. The example code I've seen uses tricks with sine and square waves to avoid doing the transform. I can sample the wave at the `AudioContext` sample rate, but I don't know how to convert an array of amplitudes into the `real` and `imag` arguments for the `createPeriodicWave` method. I cannot find any code to study, and it's taking me a while to get to grips with the math.

Comment: If speed is not important, just implement the formulas for the [discrete fourier transform](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discrete_Fourier_transform).  Or do a search for Javascript FFT.  There are lots of Javascript implementations of an FFT.  The transform will produce an array of complex values (or two separate arrays).  The real part is the `real` parameter and the imaginary part is the `imag` parrameter for a `PeriodicWave`.

Comment: I couldn't find any maintained libraries that implement FFT in JS. Other people have had the same issue.

Comment: An implementation of an FFT doesn't need constant upgrading.  It should just basically work.  I wrote one long ago for Chrome.  It works for what I needed, and I don't need to update it constantly.  May not be the fastest, but fast enough for me.  The alternative is to compile up your favorite C/C++ FFT code using wasm to run in the browser.

Comment: No worries. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

I just wrote [an implementation of this](https://rawcdn.githack.com/voscarmv/coding_behind_the_scenes/c7d78652b72093cd5afcdd4d6267d76864119abd/soundwave/synth/sound.html). To use it, drag and drop the squares to form a waveform and then play the piano that appears afterwards. Watch the video in [this tweet](https://twitter.com/VOscarMV/status/1254632956351721472?s=20) to see a use example. The live demo is in alpha version, so the code and UI are a little rough. You can check out the source [here](https://github.com/voscarmv/coding_behind_the_scenes/tree/c7d78652b72093cd5afcdd4d6267d76864119abd/soundwave/synth).

I didn't write any documentation, but I recorded some videos [(Video 1)](https://youtu.be/-sR9qjsdv1k) [(Video 2)](https://youtu.be/5umo92UbE7c) [(Video 3)](https://youtu.be/5umo92UbE7c) of me coding the project live. They should be pretty self-explanatory. There are a couple of bugs in there that I fixed later. For the working version, please refer to the github link.